# How to tell journalctl do display exactly two priorities?

Tags: systemd, journalctl

I would like to show only `crit` and `info` and nothing in between.

I tried:

```
journalctl -p 2..2 -p 6..6
```

But it doesn't work. The second argument seems to override the first.

The following code produces a syntax error:

```
journalctl -p 2,6
```

How can I retrieve only two priorities without any values in between?

I'm searching for a more concise solution than this.

```
journalctl -o json | jq --argjson p '{"2":"CRIT","6":"INFO"}' --raw-output 'select(.PRIORITY == "2" or .PRIORITY == "6") | "\(.__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP | tonumber / 1000 / 1000 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) \($p[.PRIORITY]) \(.MESSAGE)"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify it as a raw filter, as you already know the fields:

```
journalctl PRIORITY=2 + PRIORITY=6
```

While the filter syntax is not very expressive, it does support one level of 'OR' operation using `+`. (For example, `journalctl A B C + D E` means "(A && B && C) || (D && E)".)